# Data model to use for a DVR's recording schedule

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, collections

A DVR needs to store a list of programs to record. Each program has a starting time and duration. This data needs to be stored in a way that allows the system to quickly determine if a new recording request conflicts with existing scheduled recordings.

The issue is that merely looking to see if there is a show with a conflicting start time is inadequate because the end of a longer program can overlap with a shorter one. I suppose one could create a data structure that tracked the availability of each time slice, perhaps at half-hour granularity, but this would fail if we cannot assume all shows start and end at the half-hour boundary, and tracking at the minute level seems inefficient, both in storage and look up.

Is there a data structure that allows one to query by range, where you supply the lower and upper bound and it returns a collection of all elements that fall within or overlap that range?

Comment: I think @Erik's suggestion is good.  Two suggestions: you may need to address those programs that recur, and time is "circular", so be careful about handling shows that cross midnight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An [interval tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree) (maybe using the [augmented tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree#Augmented_tree) data structure?) does exactly what you're looking for. You'd enter all scheduled recordings into the tree and when a new request comes in, check whether it overlaps any of the existing intervals. Both this lookup and adding a new request take O(log(n)) time, where n is the number of intervals currently stored.